# Excel poi loses column formatting

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I create an empy excel and I format an entire column (color, number editing, etc), then I add rows into it with the old poi-3.9 and xls. 
The resulting xls has the column with number well formatted.

The same with newest poi-3.17 and xlsx results in a new xlsx with column formatting lost. With or without streaming makes no difference.

Thanks for help. 
Giuseppe.

Comment: Are you applying the cell styles you want to the new cells you create?

Comment: Yes, `HSSFCell` does respecting the column style when new created but `XSSFCell` does not. So in `XSSF` you need setting the needed cell style to each new created `XSSFCell` via `XSSFCell.setCellStyle`. I am using a method `getPreferredCellStyle(Cell cell)` for this as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270297/how-to-get-cell-style-of-empty-cell-apache-poi/49282369#49282369

Comment: In 3.9 (xls) the new cells inherit the column formatting of the template. For example if I set the cell format to "#\/0?" for the entire column in the template, the new number inserted appears as "12345/12". In 3.17 (xlsx) the new number appears as  "1234512" without any style.

Comment: This behavior is not dependent on the `apache poi` version (3.9 vs. 3.17) but is depemdent on the `Excel` file format used: `HSSF` (`*.xls` - `BIFF` format) vs. `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`- `Office Open XML` format).

Comment: Hi Axel, I've used the getPreferredCellStyle and I think I've got it ! Thanks.