# POI says Cellstyle is empty but cell has a Style

Tags: java, apache-poi

`POI` says `Cellstyle` is empty but cell has a Style.

I Only get `Cell value` I need a `Cell style` & background style. What the problem? Please give a suggestions

I'm using latest version jar of POI.(`poi-4.0.1.jar,poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar,poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.1.jar`).

Comment: I think you're missing a semi-colon. Well, maybe not, but how would we know, since we can't see any code at all?

Comment: Cells having a cell value always have the used style directly set, at least if the file was saved from `Excel`. Empty cells may show the row style or column style which will not be got via [Cell.getCellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellStyle--). For this I have provided [public CellStyle getPreferredCellStyle(Cell cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270297/how-to-get-cell-style-of-empty-cell-apache-poi/49282369#49282369). Try whether this method fulfills yor requirements.